# What is involved in simultaneous editing of a file?

Tags: editing, collaboration, file-type

I'm curious about the ability to simultaneously edit files. How it works, when can't it work.
For example, if I put any number of files up on a network share (or maybe DropBox) it's usually not possible to collaborate on them with someone else.
Let's say I want to work on a SolidWorks model with someone else. Is it SolidWorks that locks up the file, is it something that needs to be build into the filetype, or a combination of these?

Ultimately I'm thinking of cool things to do with node.js and socket.io and simultaneously messing with files.

Edit: If anyone knows what Google Docs and other online office suites are doing in the background I'd love specific explanations too.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using some sort of source control software.  It seems like that might be the correct technology for what you are describing.  I recently started using Visual SVN.  It's free, easy and effective.

http://www.visualsvn.com/